# Blender GLTF export does not include shader

Tags: materials, shaders, export, gltf

I have a 3D model that looks like this:
[image]

It basically has two mashes, the pink one only has a base color value but the bottom one has some shader information:
[image]

When I try to export it to a GLTF file, the shader of the bottom one does not export for some reason and the model looks like this:

[image]

Can anyone help enlighten me on why this is happening?

Blend file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IgwZo3mw3mxJ_RXkLnv6UcQQshZIV0mB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: [This](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html) is the Blender manual section on the GlTF exporter. The Exported Materials section on that page goes into some detail on what is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

That's normal, procedural shaders can't really be exported.

What you should do is either bake your procedural texture into an image texture, or paint an image texture.

Comment: I baked it to an image texture and it worked. However, there is a thin black line in the middle of the donut. I made a online demo https://corek.herokuapp.com/ . In this example model is scaled by 5 so the line looks bigger than it should be. Can you tell me why might this be happening

Comment: This can be multiple reasons, but usually because either you have UV islands too close to each other, or your baking margins are too big (causing other islands to bleed on each other) or too thin (causing the inside of islands to have unbaked parts), sometimes even both.
Since you are using a real time engine to preview, then the issue can be emphasized by it since it often use mipmapping, which reduces down the resulution and might make this kind of issue extremely apparent. Learn more about it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MVsIIkJNkjM)